# How to tell if object is an enum?

Tags: c#, silverlight, enums, ivalueconverter

I'm not a C# wizard, but there has to be a simple solution for this.

I have an `IValueConverter` for a `DataTemplate`. The converter will be used in a control whose data is bound to an object of type `enum`: `public enum ContentTypes`. I want to write a generic converter that can take any `enum` and then do something with it however when the converter below does it's thing the object parameter's type is `ContentTypes` rather than `Enum`.

The `Convert` method:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
   Type valueType = value.GetType();    // <-- evaluates to `ContentTypes`. How can I just see if it's an enum, or Enum? 

   if (value.GetType() == typeof(Enum))
   {
       // Do something .... 
   }

   return null;
}
```

So, is it possible to take an object of unknown type and determine if it is an `enum` and cast it to such an enum, generically? I'm missing something basic.

Comment: would this be a good example for the use of `is` for comparison and `as` for casting?

Comment: @Jonathan I guess `if (value is Enum) { ... }` would work. Here `Enum` refers to `System.Enum` (`using System;` assumed). And if `value` is actually `null` then `value.GetType().IsEnum` will throw while `value is Enum` will just be false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Type.IsEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum.aspx) property, which does exactly that.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed. High-fives all around.